# login redirects to unavilable when i use Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

What i need to do es login to this website: https://prenotami.esteri.it/
up until a couple of days it was working fine logging with Selenium

Version:
Python 3.9.7
Selenium 4.7.2
Requests 2.28.2

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import datetime, time

#Script Prenotami
website = 'https://prenotami.esteri.it/'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options, desired_capabilities=caps)

start_time=datetime.datetime.now()
driver.get(website)
driver.maximize_window()
#email
print("mail")
driver.find_element(By.ID,'login-email').send_keys('USERNAME')
time.sleep(10)
#Password
print("pwd")
driver.find_element(By.ID,'login-password').send_keys('PASSWORD')
time.sleep(10)
#AVANTI
print("AVANTI")
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'button.primary.g-recaptcha').click()
time.sleep(30)
```

If you successfully log in it should show this:
[success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMgzx.png)

But right now when i use the script it shows a page that says **Unavailable**
`<html><head><title>Unavailable</title></head><body>Unavailable</body></html>`

I have tried sending a request directly to the login form with requests because maybe it was a problem with

```
import requests

with requests.session() as session:
    #Login
    login = "https://prenotami.esteri.it/Home/Login"
    data = {
        'Email': 'USER',
        'Password': 'PASSWORD',
    }
    response = session.post(login, data)
    print(response.text)
```

but the outcome is the same, Unavailable

My questions is: i know it has something to do with recaptcha, it has the sitekey and a data-callback on the submit button but i cant seem to find out how to fix this, have anyone encountered with something like this?

thanks!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: did you try using undetected selenium?

Comment: I'm having the same kind of problem with Selenium and a google search brought me here.  Turns out we're both trying to log into the same site!

Have you found a solution?

Comment: i couldnt make it work so i moved to requests and now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The Unavailable occurs because after POST to https://prenotami.esteri.it/Home/Login the response is empty and has a GET redirect to https://prenotami.esteri.it/UserArea. Good luck!